# how to convert video from one format to another using php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, video-conversion

hi i want to include the vedio download option in my webpage. I am using ffmpeg, but  it seems to work very slow. Is there is any other way to do this or how to spead up the ffmpeg.
i am using this code to get the frames from the vedio.

to convert the vedio

```
$call="ffmpeg -i ".$_SESSION['video_to_convert']." -vcodec libvpx  -r 30 -b ".$quality." -acodec libvorbis -ab 128000   -ar ".$audio." -ac 2 -s ".$size." ".$converted_vids.$name.".".$type." -y 2> log/".$name.".txt";
$convert = (popen("start /b ".$call, "r"));
pclose($convert);
```

to get the frame from the vedio

```
exec("ffmpeg -vframes 1 -ss ".$time_in_seconds." -i $converted_vids video_images.jpg -y 2>);
```

but this code does not generate any error its loading continously.

Comment: Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What are you trying to accomplish (Vedio?)? 2. What have you tried so far, specifically (code samples?)? 3. What results did you get? 4. How did that differ from the results you were expecting? (no, it's not self-evident, that's why I'm asking)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1):

Cache or pre-generate the output format.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ffmpeg-php](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/) library. Should boost up some processes rather then manually calling the ffmpeg command line tool using exec.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first of all take PHP out of the equasion and time how long it takes to do what you're after via the command line.

Once you're happy that works the way you'd like it to, make sure you've tweaked your script's execution time (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to accomodate what's likely to take a while.

Consider an async approach if it's getting in the way of UX.

Ta